# The meaning of the acquire release fence abstract instruction realization of different platform

Tags: java, c++, jvm, instruction-set

See the following code:

```
//               sparc RMO             ia64             x86
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// fence         membar #LoadStore |   mf               lock addl 0,(sp)
//                      #StoreStore |
//                      #LoadLoad |
//                      #StoreLoad
//
// release       membar #LoadStore |   st.rel [sp]=r0   movl $0,<dummy>
//                      #StoreStore
//               st %g0,[]
//
// acquire       ld [%sp],%g0          ld.acq <r>=[sp]  movl (sp),<r>
//               membar #LoadLoad |
//                      #LoadStore
//
// release_store membar #LoadStore |   st.rel           <store>
//                      #StoreStore
//               st
//
// store_fence   st                    st               lock xchg
//               fence                 mf
//
// load_acquire  ld                    ld.acq           <load>
//               membar #LoadLoad |
//                      #LoadStore
```

The code above is the realization of acquire/release/fence abstract instruction on different platform,I just want to know the x86 realization.

Can you explain the instructions below for me?

```
How 'movl $0,<dummy>' represent release?
How 'movl (sp),<r>' represent acquire?
How '<store>' represent release_store?
How 'lock xchg' represent store_fence?
How '<load>' represent load_acquire?
```

The code is from jdk8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/OrderAddress.hpp the 'Memory Access Ordering Model'

If you are busy,you can just tell me where can I find the instruction set information about different CPU architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x86 has "strong memory model", which means that every machine instruction comes implicitly with acquire and release semantics. You may further read [this](http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/), as well as answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7214916/3959454).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anton Savin,May I ask whether you can offer me some learning meterials about the instruction set of different architecture? I just want some tidy documents.